# Can google apps script time-based trigger cause this problem: "554 5.4.6 Too many hops 53 (50 max):"?

Tags: email, google-apps-script, sendmail

Hello I have a google docs document where I installed a simple emailing code on as follows:

```
   function sendMail() { 
        var file = DriveApp.getFileById('XXXXXXXX');
        var recipients = "mymail@group1.com" + "mymail@group2.com" + "mymail@group3.com";
        MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, 'Daily Notes', 'Please see file Attached.', {
        name: file.getName(),
        attachments: [file.getAs(MimeType.PDF)]
    }); 
  }
```

The code works fine it sends the email to multiple group emails which I want it to send. It has done this for a month now. But until recently, I keep receiving this Mail Delivery Subsystem after 20 minutes or 1 hour from the original email which is sent out and inside the error message email it says:

> "The following addresses had permanent fatal errors"

and it points to only one of the emails I send daily mails to. It also says something like this: (reason: 554 5.4.6 Too many hops). and then this:

> 554 5.4.6 Too many hops 53 (50 max).

The Good Doc's file has Google's time-driven trigger as you can see in the image below. I wonder if somehow the trigger is running twice in the time interval I gave to it. Could it be why this is happening?

[image: trigger install wizard screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

In almost all cases `554 5.4.6 Too many hops 53 (50 max)` means loop along email delivery path e.g. *server A forwards to server B, server B forwards to server A, server A forwards to sever B, …*. It is detected by counting `Received:` headers in message passing via give SMTP/email server.

Suggested fixing procedure:

- Inspect `Reveived:` headers in email bounce message to locate server(s) responsible for the loop.
- contact the relevant postmaster

---

In many years I have seen just one "real life" case when bounce message/email like that was not caused by email delivery loop.